# How to integrate /home back into main partition, then grow partition

Tags: linux, partition

I made a mistake in setting up one of our XenServer-based Linux VMs.  I created a separate swap (good) and a large separate /home directory (bad) when really it should have been a large separate /var directory instead.

Now that /var has almost saturated the root disk, I would like to reintegrate /home back into the root partition, delete the old 921GB /home partition, then grow the root partition to 921GB leaving the /swap partition untouched.

Currently:

```
[root@ /]# df -h

Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root      50G   43G  4.0G  92% / 
tmpfs                            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% 
/dev/shm /dev/xvda1              485M   72M  388M  16% /boot 
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home     921G  200M  874G   1% /home
```

So more clearly, I need to know how to move /home and it's contents to the root partition (/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root) and have Linux recognize it as the OS's home directory, delete the /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home partition, and then grow the /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root partition to take up the additional 921GB available.

I'm open to swapping /home and /var's locations if possible, but this is a production server.  I can make instant snapshots at will though, so some late night experimentation is possible! ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward, as root:

```
mkdir /home2
mv /home/* /home2/
umount -fl /home
lvremove /dev/VolGroup/lv_home
mv /home2 /home
```

- edit your fstab and remove the entry for /dev/VolGroup/lv_home
- check how much space you now have available in VolGroup with vgdisplay and add that much to lv_root with lvextend
- use resize2fs or xfs_growfs as appropriate on lv_root

Comment: Thanks very much, however I get "Logical volume VolGroup/lv_home contains a filesystem in use."  Did I need to do this in single user mode?

Comment: I mixed answers below and rebooted with the /home commented out of fstab and then removed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very useful. I'd like to add something: It's better to use "root" account in "rescue mode" so you can unmount home dir successfully (because root user uses another home dir).

Comment: According to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1705897, for Centos 8 ,it seems we must use "xfs_growfs  /" (mount point instead of device name)

Answer (score 4):

This process will work if your root filesystem is resizeable (ext4 for example).

1. modify a existing user or create a new user whose home directory is not under /home.
2. verify that you can login as that user and su to root
3. ensure all other users are logged out
4. umount /home - if this fails then user processes may still be using /home. Check with fuser or lsof
5. remount /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home on a temporary mount - /mnt/home for example
6. use rsync, cp -p or some other tool to copy the user home directories from /mnt/home to /home - verify that the permissions and ownerships are correct
7. edit fstab to comment out /home
8. users can now be allow to log back in
9. lvremove /dev/VolGroup/lv_home
10. lvextend -L+921G /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
11. resize2fs /dev/VolGroup/lv_root

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications in steps 10 and 11!  I hope people vote up this answer.

Comment: Also instead of `lvextend -L+921G /dev/VolGroup/lv_root` you can use `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/VolGroup/lv_root`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without growing the partition by just swapping the mount points:

unmount the home partition:

`umount /home`

mount it somewhere else, e.g. to /mnt:

`mount /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home /mnt`

move everything from the partition to your home directory (which is on the root partition now):

`mv /mnt/* /home/`

move the data from your /var directory to the partition:

`mv /var/* /mnt/`

remount your partition to /var:

`umount /mnt`

`mount /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_home /var`

Make sure to change the contents of your `/etc/fstab` afterwards accordingly.

Comment: Will this move the files that are held open by daemons correctly or will they continue to be written to the original ?

Comment: I'd suggest to stop any services accessing /var beforehand and start them again afterwards. Between the steps of moving the data from /var/ to /mnt and remounting to /var/, the /var directory will be empty so anything accessing it won't work anyway.